# What is the authentic source which says Shri Madhvacharya had a vison of Shri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu?

Tags: madhvacharya, iskcon, achintya-bheda-abheda, chaitanya-charitamrita, chaitanya-bhagavata

In the book [Navadvipa Dhama Mahatmya](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.purebhakti.com/resources/ebooks-magazines/bhakti-books/english/202-navadvipa-dhama-mahatmya-1/file&ved=2ahUKEwjEpsiq8MjoAhVrwTgGHWjGAcgQFjAAegQIBxAC&usg=AOvVaw0s72lTW3ucPfjapoC_mbn5), page 355, there is a mention of Shri Madhwacharya having a vision of Shri Chaotanya Mahaptabhu. This was a book written by Srila Bhakti Vinoda Thakura who lived in the 19th century.

So what is the authentic and ancient source from which he got this information?

Comment: sri Chaitanya mahaprabhu belongs to 15th-16th Century (18 February 1486 – 14 June 1534), whereas  Shri Madhwacharya    belongs to CE 1238–1317 .  I don't think it's possible

Comment: He had a vision it seems

Comment: Do you meant to say that Shri Madhwacharya had a vision of Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu, who came 2 centuries later to Shri Madhwacharya ?

Comment: @srimannarayanakv yes that's what the book claims, please read it, it's on page 355

Comment: Let the followers of Sri Madwacharya respond, to the claim of Gaudiya Vaishnavas.  Tomorrow another person from that sect may claim that Sri Chaitanya Mahaprabhu gave darshan to Sri Ramanujacharya also.  :-)  As far as I am concerned, it is quite hilarious.  Thanks

Comment: @@srimannarayanakv not tomorrow it's already claimed hahaha

Comment: Wait I'll send you the link

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106219/discussion-between-varun-n-rao-and-srimannarayana-k-v).